# How to call from application to phone number

Tags: iphone, phone-call

I am displaying Business card view on which I have one button on which I am setting Button title as phone number string which I got after parsing. I am getting perfect phone number string value on the button title. Now by pressing that button I want to call the default phone app so that User can call.

```
 -(void) BcardDisp: (id)sender
   {
BGView.hidden = NO;
if(BcardView.hidden == YES)
{

BcardView.hidden = NO;

NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    marker *aMarker = (marker *)[appDelegate.markers objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
for (int selectedIndexPath = 0; selectedIndexPath < [appDelegate.markers count]; selectedIndexPath++)
{

ShowroomName.text = aMarker.name;
    Address_Bcard.numberOfLines=3;
    Address_Bcard.text =aMarker.address;

    [p_Bcard setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aMarker.phone]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:YES];
}
```

}

For Calling number I am using following action on Button.

```
 - (IBAction)callfrom_BcardVeiw
  {
marker *aMarker = [[marker alloc] init];
NSURL *phoneNumberURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aMarker.phone]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumberURL];
NSLog(@"%d",phoneNumberURL);

  }
```

But I am not able to call.....getting grabage value. What logic should I put under my - (IBAction)callfrom_BcardVeiw ....so that I can call on the same number as Button title string.

Comment: Hello everyone...Can we also call the edit contact window by url. I am adding contact through application and I want to open the contact window with detail just have added so user can save or discard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSURL *phoneNumberURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",aMarker.phone]];
```

Comment: it still give me grabage value as 1051136 instead of  "022 2294 8602" as I put NSLog.....not able to call:(

Comment: Try with %@ instead of %d, are you sure that the phone number are correctly?

Comment: You create a object marker but didn't put any value to the object, unless you init with  default value in the init methods, if you didn't aMarker.phone has a garbage value

Comment: Yes I have set custom button tital as 022 2294 8602 which I am perfectely getting. But by pressing the same button giving action on it not working.

Comment: By the way I try %@ this....this opening call application with only 4 digit number. I mean iPhone call start with 6865 number instead of 022 2294 8602

Comment: But, when you assign the title of the button to the object?

Comment: See my  -(void) BcardDisp: (id)sender{    [p_Bcard setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aMarker.phone]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} .........On this button I am displaying my Business card view with custom phone button with title

Comment: Yes, but then when you do - (IBAction)callfrom_BcardVeiw create a new object marker *aMarker = [[marker alloc] init]; empty

Comment: Ok so What should I put here in my (IBAction)callfrom_BcardVeiw to get exact phone number string

Comment: You have to put 022 2294 8602 before in aMarker.phone

Comment: actually I am getting this number by parsing. And from every tableview cell I have Business card button with respective view on which Phone number button with different phone number. How can I put only 022 2294 8602.

Comment: You have to assing the button title in the IBACtion to  aMarker

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the phone URL with "tel://".

Be careful too, Is aMarker.phone an integer or a string?

In one part of your code you use "%d" so it assumes it is an integer, and in the other part of your code you use "%@", which assumes it is a `NSObject`, probably an `NSString`.

I bet the phone number is a string (as it can contains characters others than digits, namely "+" for intl prefixes, or "*" or "#" for some services...) so you need to use `@"tel://%@"` and not `@"tel://%d"` or it will format strange values in your URL (the address of the string in memory, to be precise) instead of the actual phone number.

On the other hand, if the phone number is an integer (would be strange but your use of "%d" makes me perplex) and you use "%@", your code will crash, trying to access description method on some integer value that is not an NSObject (it will consider the integer as an address of an NSObject in memory whereas it is not, which will explain the BAD_ACCESS)

Comment: Don't add the `//` just `tel:` will do, also allways ask the system if it can open the url. Because your app might be running on a iPad or iPod touch which will not allow the phone all.

Comment: yes By using %@ it is making phone call but only with 4 digit number 6855 instead of 022 2294 8602

Answer (score 0):

Remove any space, or other charters that are not needed:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [aMarker.phone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

NSURL *phoneNumberURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneNumberURL ]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumberURL];
} else {
   // iPad or iPod Touch, can't make a call
}
```